# How to store fixed row values in a variable - SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which can have a maximum of 5 rows and minimum 1 row. Now I need to store these rows in different variable like `@v1,@v2,@v3,@v4,@v5`. How can I do it?

The Table has only 1 column `custid`.

```
CustId
100
200
300
400
```

If the table contain only 1 row then `@v1` should have that value and rest can be `null`.

Comment: This [LINK](http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Converting%20row%20values%20in%20a%20table%20to%20a%20single%20concatenated%20string.aspx) might help. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT @v1 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN CustId END),
       @v2 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN CustId END),
       @v3 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN CustId END),
       @v4 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN CustId END),
       @v5 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN CustId END)
FROM (
   SELECT CustId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustId) AS rn
   FROM mytable ) t
```

Using `ROW_NUMBER` you assign a distinct number to each record of your table. Then, using *conditional aggregates* in an outer query you can consume this number in order to set each separate variable.

If there are less than 5 rows, the corresponding variables will be set to `NULL`.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7bce0/1)

Answer (score 5):

If you have SQL Server 2012 or newer, you can try [LAG()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) function.

```
SELECT 
    @v1 = custID
  , @v2 = LAG(custID, 1) OVER (ORDER BY custID DESC)
  , @v3 = LAG(custID, 2) OVER (ORDER BY custID DESC)
  , @v4 = LAG(custID, 3) OVER (ORDER BY custID DESC)
  , @v5 = LAG(custID, 4) OVER (ORDER BY custID DESC)
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CustID DESC
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a96e5/7)

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
create table #tab
(
    custID int
)

insert into #tab
select 110 union all
select 120 union all
select 130 union all
select 140 union all
select 150

declare @v1 int,@v2 int, @v3 int, @v4 int, @v5 int

select @v1 = custID
from  #tab
order by custid 
OFFSET 0 row
FETCH  NEXT 1 ROW ONLY

select @v2 = custID
from  #tab
order by custid 
OFFSET 1 row
FETCH  NEXT 1 ROW ONLY

select @v3 = custID
from  #tab
order by custid 
OFFSET 2 row
FETCH  NEXT 1 ROW ONLY

select @v4 = custID
from  #tab
order by custid 
OFFSET 3 row
FETCH  NEXT 1 ROW ONLY


select @v5 = custID
from  #tab
order by custid 
OFFSET 4 row
FETCH  NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
select @v1,@v2,@v3,@v4,@v5
```

Answer (score 1):

we can achieve this even using **PIVOT** function and with the help **Row_number**

```
declare @mytable  table  (CustId int)
insert into @mytable values
(100), (200), (300), (400),(500)


SELECT  [1] as V1, [2]as V2, [3]as V3, [4]as V4, [5]as V5
FROM
(SELECT CustId,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustId) AS value
    FROM @mytable ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
max(CustId)
FOR value  IN ([1], [2], [3], [4],[5])
) AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, one brutal approach:

```
Select @v1 = t1.CustID,
       @v2 = oa2.CustID, 
       @v3 = oa3.CustID, 
       @v4 = oa4.CustID, 
       @v5 = oa5.CustID
from Table t1
outer apply(select top 1 CustID from Table t2 where t2.CustID not in(t1.CustID) order by CustID) oa2
outer apply(select top 1 CustID from Table t3 where t3.CustID not in(t1.CustID, oa2.CustID) Order by CustID) oa3
outer apply(select top 1 CustID from Table t4 where t4.CustID not in(t1.CustID, oa2.CustID, oa3.CustID) Order by CustID) oa4
outer apply(select top 1 CustID from Table t5 where t5.CustID not in(t1.CustID, oa2.CustID, oa3.CustID, oa4.CustID) Order by CustID) oa5
```